# VBA : Target.Value, change the cell

Tags: excel, vba, list

I would like to click on E15 and put the value from E16. How can I do that ?
My code is :

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim i As Integer
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C6")) Is Nothing Then
        Call CLICK_BTN_INFOS_CONTRAT
    End If

    Dim TabRes() As String
    If Target.Value = [E15].Value Then
        ReDim TabRes(0 To UBound(Split([Target], ",")))
        For i = LBound(TabRes) To UBound(TabRes)
            TabRes(i) = Split(Split([Target], ",")(i), "-")(1)
             MsgBox TabRes(0)
            GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE TabRes(0)
        Next i
        
    End If
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong event handler. In terms of what you ask, see below code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("E15")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Value = Target.Offset(0,1).Value
        'or
        'Target.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("E16").Value
        'or
        'ActiveSheet.Range("E15").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("E16").Value
    End If
    
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

After seeing your comments I am editing. If you are selecting from a dropdown then your event handler is correct, i.e. `Worksheet_Change()`. The below should meet your requirements..

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("E15")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim inputString As String
        Dim stringArray As Variant
        Dim argString as String
        
        'store E15 to a string variable
        inputString = Target.Value
        'create array from string
        stringArray = Split(inputString, " ")
        'store E16 to variable to pass to function call
        argString = Target.Offset(1, 0).Value
        'call function
        GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE(argString)
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Seem doesn't work. I would like click on the list, E15, choose the data in E15 by click, the data in E16 is also cnanged. I would like to run the GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE with E16. I put the image to my message.

Comment: What data changes in `E16`? What is `GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE`?

Comment: In E15 I have the data like this : A PLUS FINANCE - 927
AB COURTAGE - A17819

Comment: In E16 i have the list with 927, A17819

Comment: So if I click on A PLUS FINANCE - 927 in E15

Comment: I will have 927 in E16

Comment: I put the code of GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE in my message

Comment: Thank you ! But I don't need to do the output to E16, the values are already exist in E16.

Comment: I would like just to take the values from E16, it will simplify my code, beacause I use the  split in TabRes(i) = Split(Split([Target], ",")(i), "-")(1)

Comment: I would like click on E15 and take the value form E16 :)

Comment: What do you want to do with the value in E16?

Comment: E16 is input for GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227494/discussion-between-dean-and-marie).